# Keycloak Multitenancy static Content Return 404

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, microservices, keycloak

I'm working on modernizing monolithic application to be microservice based application supporting multi tenancy using Spring boot, Keycloak 17, the configuration is Keycloak configuration file depending on the path referring to this [example](https://czetsuya.medium.com/how-to-implement-multitenancy-with-spring-boot-and-keycloak-36be8570005a)

For me it it working, and can load the deployments from json, login, below is the url for the application and I'm parsing branch1 after "tenant" without issues

> http://localhost:8100/tenant/branch1/

**The main issue is rendering css and JS files which is containing tenant name knwoing that I'm using sing WAR
with multiple realms**

`http://localhost:8100/tenant/branch1/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js` --> return 404 which is not exist

*Actual code for including static contents*

in The jsp files I'm reading css/js files as before `<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

*keycloal json file example*

```
{"realm": "branch1",
 "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8181/",
 "ssl-required": "external",
 "resource": "app",
 "public-client": true,
 "confidential-port": 0,
 "principal-attribute": "preferred_username"}
```

**Please advise**

1. rendering static content
2. is there any guidance after authentication to return one URL without tenant/branch1 specially I'm using CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver inside my application

@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "keycloak.config", name = "resolver", havingValue = "path")
public class PathBasedConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {

```
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, KeycloakDeployment> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static AdapterConfig adapterConfig;

    @Override
    public KeycloakDeployment resolve(OIDCHttpFacade.Request request) {

        System.out.println("inside resolve :: ");
        String realm = SubdomainUtils.obtainTenantFromSubdomain(request.getURI());

        if (realm.contains("?")) {
            realm = realm.split("\\?")[0];
        }

        if (!cache.containsKey(realm)) {
            InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + realm + "-keycloak.json");
            cache.put(realm, KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(is));
        }

        return cache.get(realm);
    }

    static void setAdapterConfig(AdapterConfig adapterConfig) {
        PathBasedConfigResolver.adapterConfig = adapterConfig;
    }

}


public class SpringKeycloakSecurityConfiguration {

@DependsOn("keycloakConfigResolver")
@KeycloakConfiguration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "keycloak.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public static class KeycloakConfigurationAdapter extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        SimpleAuthorityMapper soa = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(soa);
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        // required for bearer-only applications.
        // return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() throws Exception {
        return new MultitenantKeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint(adapterDeploymentContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                authenticationManager(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/tenant/*/sso/login"));
        filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
        return filter;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(
            KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    /**
     * Configuration spécifique à keycloak (ajouts de filtres, etc)
     * 
     * @param http
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                // use previously declared bean
                .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())

                // keycloak filters for securisation
                .and().addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), X509AuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())

                .and().logout().addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler()).logoutUrl("/tenant/*/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(
                        // logout handler for API
                        (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                Authentication authentication) -> response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK))
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("mobileservlet/**").permitAll().antMatchers("**/favicon.ico")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/error").permitAll().antMatchers("/login.go").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name(), "GET", "POST"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(
                Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MultitenantKeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint extends KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint {

public MultitenantKeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint(AdapterDeploymentContext adapterDeploymentContext) {
    super(adapterDeploymentContext);
}

public MultitenantKeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint(AdapterDeploymentContext adapterDeploymentContext, RequestMatcher apiRequestMatcher) {
    super(adapterDeploymentContext, apiRequestMatcher);
}

@Override
protected void commenceLoginRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("inside commenceLoginRedirect :: ");
    
    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    int multitenantIndex = path.indexOf("tenant/");
    if (multitenantIndex == -1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not able to resolve the realm from the request path!");
    }

    String realm = path.substring(path.indexOf("tenant/")).split("/")[1];
    if (realm.contains("?")) {
        realm = realm.split("\\?")[0];
    }

    String contextAwareLoginUri = request.getContextPath() + "/tenant/" + realm + DEFAULT_LOGIN_URI;
    response.sendRedirect(contextAwareLoginUri);
}
```

}

Comment: If you make your static content as public access. then it will resolve the issue. 
Please keep out of resource server. @gasser

Comment: I tried to .antMatchers("/resources/*").permitAll() in security configuration, but every request being passed by PathBasedConfigResolver first. is that what you mean ?

Comment: if those are static file. then you can skip storing in resource server.
example : 

https://cdn.my.net/tenat1/static-file.css 
https://cdn.my.net/tenat2/static-file.css 
https://cdn.my.net/tenat3/static-file.css

Answer (score 0):

Bad news, the Keycloak adapters for spring you are using are very [deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Don't use it.

Better news, I host [spring-boot starters for resource-servers](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) which support multi-tenancy: accept identities issued by more than just one issuer (as many realms as you need in your case) and retrieve "roles" from realms and clients with the mapping you want (control case and prefix). It also enables you to configure "public" routes and CORS configuration from preperties file (plus a few more things).

Configuration for `realm1` and `other-realm` both used by two clients (`some client` and `other-client`) is as simple as:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <!-- replace "webflux" with "webmvc" if your app is a servlet -->
    <!-- replace "jwt" with "introspecting" to use token introspection instead of JWT decoding -->
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <!-- this version is to be used with spring-boot 3.0.0-RC2, use 5.x for spring-boot 2.6.x or before -->
    <version>6.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig { }
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/realm1
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,ressource_access.some-client.roles,ressource_access.other-client.roles
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[1].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/other-realm
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[1].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,ressource_access.some-client.roles,ressource_access.other-client.roles

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/some-api
```